# ArrayList of custom objects gets 'incorrectly' updated

Tags: android, class, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of custom Objects named Player. The ArrayList is shown in a RecyclerView - which works well. I added an onClick in my RecyclerAdapter for each TextView, passing my ArrayList, the clicked column and the clicked row - works also really good.

I let the user enter a score for this "cell" - and try to update my ArrayList.
The problem is, that the score is set for all players in the ArrayList.
The RecyclerView gets updatet "properly" - each player has the score shown in the ArrayList. What am I doing wrong? :/

```
public class Player{
    String name;
    int[] sections = new int[16]; 

    public Player() {
        super();
    }

    public Player(String name, int[] sections) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.sections = sections;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPoints(int section){
        return sections[section];
    }

    public void setPoints(int section, int punkte){
        this.sections[section] = punkte;
    }

    public int[] getAllPoints(){
        return sections;
    }
}
```

I create my ArrayList spielerArrayList like this in the onCreate Method of my second activity, getting the names (ArrayList spielernamen) from the main activity:

```
public void getData() {
        int[] foo = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        if (spielernamen != null) {
            for (String spielername : spielernamen) {
                spielerArrayList.add(new Player(spielername, foo));
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and a Code snippet from my method which is called onItemClick: (problem seems to be here or in Player class)

```
Player spieler = playerArrayList.get(column)

punkte = numberPicker.getValue();
spieler.setPoints(row, punkte); 
playerArrayList.set(column, spieler);
```

The problem seems to be in this lines. I get the Player object long before and set an AlertDialog, if that changes anything I'll post the whole code.
I also tried this, but the error stays - every Player object gets the entered score.

```
Player spieler = playerArrayList.get(column)

punkte = numberPicker.getValue();
int[] pointsarray = spieler.getAllPoints();
pointsarray[row] = punkte;
Player player = new Player(spieler.getName(), pointsarray);
playerArrayList.remove(column);
playerArrayList.add(column, player);
```

Tell me if you need more code or something. :)

Comment: `spieler` is an object of `Player` class but I don't see any method in it as `setPunkte()` and `getAllPunkte()` but you have used them.

Comment: That was an mistake in translating the methods, i'll correct it, sorry x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all Player object reference to a same array object.So when you modify one of these objects, all of objects will be modified.Try to initialize the Player object

```
public void getData() {
    int[] foo = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    if (spielernamen != null) {
        for (String spielername : spielernamen) {
            // here, each Player object have same member array object foo
            spielerArrayList.add(new Player(spielername, foo));
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

modify to:

```
public void getData() {
    if (spielernamen != null) {
        for (String spielername : spielernamen) {
            // here, each Player object have same member array object foo
            int[] foo = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
            spielerArrayList.add(new Player(spielername, foo));
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was my mistake. I moved the `int[] foo = ...` into the loop. And it's working. Thanks!!